# Find the area of the shaded region below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, plane-geometry

> If $A$, $B$ and $T$ are points of tangency, and the radius of the quadrant measures $\sqrt2+1$, calculate the area of the shaded region.
> <sup>(Answer:$\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-1)$</sup>
>
> [image]

##### My progress:

$HC = \sqrt2+1:\angle HDC = \angle HCD = 45^\circ$

$DH=CH \implies \triangle CHD{~\text{(isosceles)}}$

$CD^2=2(\sqrt2+1)^2=6+4\sqrt2 \implies CD = \sqrt{6+4\sqrt2}$

I couldn't finish

[image]

Comment: @JeanMarie  Another view is always welcome

Comment: In fact, I have realized that my solution was more or less the same as the solution given. The only difference is that I use analytical goemetry at one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your diagram, with a line, a point and couple of line lengths added:

[image: Diagram of OP, with line VM, plus lengths r and h, added]

As shown, have $\lvert KT\rvert = \lvert KB\rvert = \lvert HB\rvert = r$. Thus, $\lvert KH\rvert = \lvert HT\rvert - \lvert KT\rvert = (\sqrt{2} + 1) - r$. With the isosceles right-angled $\triangle KBH$, the hypotenuse length is $\sqrt{2}$ times the leg lengths, so

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{2} + 1 - r & = \sqrt{2}r \\
(\sqrt{2} + 1)r & = \sqrt{2} + 1 \\
r & = 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Also as shown, draw from $V$ the line perpendicular to $HC$, with it meeting at $M$. Let $\lvert VM\rvert = h$, so $\lvert HM\rvert = h$ as well. Then since $\triangle AHC \sim \triangle VMC$, we have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\lvert AH\rvert}{\lvert HC\rvert} & = \frac{\lvert VM\rvert}{\lvert MC\rvert} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1} & = \frac{h}{\sqrt{2} + 1 - h} \\
\sqrt{2} + 1 - h & = h(\sqrt{2} + 1) \\
(2 + \sqrt{2})h & = \sqrt{2} + 1 \\
\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2} + 1)h & = \sqrt{2} + 1 \\
h & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This means

$$\lvert VH\rvert = \sqrt{2}h \;\;\to\;\; \lvert VH\rvert = 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Also, we have

$$\lvert VK\rvert = \lvert HK\rvert - \lvert VH\rvert = \sqrt{2} - 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Using $VK$ as the base, the height of $\triangle VKB$ is

$$\frac{1}{2}\lvert AB\rvert = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

With $A$ being the area of the darker shaded region, as it's the quarter circle area minus twice the area of $\triangle VKB$, we get using \eqref{eq1A}, \eqref{eq4A} and \eqref{eq5A} that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
A & = \frac{1}{4}(\pi(1^2)) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\sqrt{2} - 1) \\
& = \frac{\pi}{4} - 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
& = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - 1
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$